# Wagtail Draftail editor removes whitespace at the boundary of overlapping or composite HTML tags

Tags: django, wagtail, draftjs, templatetags

I may be missing something but am not able to crack this one.

Any text with only bold or only italic works fine, e.g.
**You may not believe what is happening!** or *You may not believe what is happening!*.

But if I have something like this:
**You may *not believe* what is happening!**
It shows correctly in the first publish. But if I reload the editor and republish the page, it becomes this:
**You may*not believe* what is happening!**

That is, the space between **may** and ***not*** is gone!
Same is true for other tags as well, e.g. bold with hyperlink etc., and even for the custom tags I've created.
This is messing up so many of my pages. Experts, please help.

---

**Update:** I found the underlying reason but still don't know how I can fix it - it is happening partially because of the spaceless templatetag (from Django), but **triggered by Draftail**. Draftail changes:

```
<b>may </b><b><i>not</i></b>
```

to:

```
<b>may</b> <b><i>not</i></b>
```

while saving the page to database. That is, the ending space is moved outside the tag. And space between tags is exactly what spaceless is supposed to remove.

Also, I think it's a draft.js question, but why does it even need to split the tags? Can't it simply do: `<b>may <i>not</i></b>`?

Comment: Sounds like this could be a bug in Wagtail - please feel encouraged to report it through the bug tracker at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues .

Comment: @gasman Amazing, following the process to report it as a bug, installed fresh Wagtail, and I've not been able to replicate the issue yet. Now I'm banging my head finding what is different in my installation (which I've upgraded to 2.11).

Thanks for the lightning fast reply. I'll update my question asap.

Comment: @gasman reported a bug: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6710